# Are translated versions of the Pluggable Transports Tor Browser Bundles available for download?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, pluggable-transports

The "standard" TBB has options to download it in many languages via the drop-down (https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en).  However, the Pluggable Transports version, which is specifically useful for a small (so far) list of countries appear to only be available in English (https://www.torproject.org/docs/pluggable-transports.html.en#download).

Are translated versions hiding somewhere in a download directory, or are they simply not yet available?

Comment: Currently they are only available in English. This might be the case because it has not been called stable, yet. Once everything can be automated there could be localized versions. (No answer, just adding thoughts)

Answer (score 0):

*It's not necessary for them to make separate package just for another language.
you can change the language in Vidalia control panel --> settings --> appearance --> language.*

I'm sorry, I was in hurry.
in the mirror sites [Tor's mirror](https://www.torproject.org/getinvolved/mirrors.html.en) I found these http://torproject.lightning-bolt.net/dist/torbrowser/

Comment: This would only change the interface language for Vidalia, which is about to be deprecated (for the browser bundles). The browser itself would be in English.

Comment: On the linked mirror there is only an English package of Tor Pluggable Transport Browser.